# Error: referenceError: ErrorEvent is not defined

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am getting this error when i am trying to get data from my `json-server`.
`baseURL` is defined and is accessible eg by my browser so there is no problem on this end.

Any suggestions welcome.

code in dish.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { baseURL } from '../shared/baseURL';
import { ProcessHTTPMsgService } from './process-httpmsg.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DishService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private processHTTPMsgService: ProcessHTTPMsgService) { }

  getDishes(): Observable<Dish[]> {
    return this.http.get<Dish[]>(baseURL + 'dishes')
      .pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
  }

  getDish(id: string): Observable<Dish> {
    return this.http.get<Dish>(baseURL + 'dishes/' + id)
      .pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
  }

  getFeaturedDish(): Observable<Dish> {
    return this.http.get<Dish[]>(baseURL + 'dishes?featured=true').pipe(map(dishes => dishes[0]))
      .pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
```

which is calling process-httpmsg.service.ts in case of error

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProcessHTTPMsgService {

  constructor() { }

  public handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse | any) {
    let errMsg: string;

    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errMsg = error.error.message;
      console.log('errMsg (is instanceof ErrorEvent): ', errMsg)
    } else {
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${error.message}`;
      console.log('errMsg (is NOT instanceof ErrorEvent): ', errMsg)
    }

    return throwError(errMsg);
  }
}
```

Comment: You aren’t importing anything called ErrorEvent, where are you expecting that to come from? That’s not a native object to Node/JavaScript called ErrorEvent.

Comment: I think Alexander is wrong, cuz it is a js object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ErrorEvent

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong though, because your code seems perfect and I don't understand. If you could provide the whole erros message, that's be helpful (collapsed, not expanded, that's way too long and not-useful)

Comment: According to me what you want to / should be building, is a solution based on a HTTPInterceptor which can catch errors from any http/https calls and where you can also decide on how the manage these error.

Comment: As @jcuypers mentioned already, you must try to use an interceptor which is the ideal way. Which platform you are facing this issue and What is your OS version on device you are testing with? Is the end point is secured (https)?

Comment: Have you got the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but this information might be helpful.

I got similar issue, ErrorEvent reference error in IE9.

Upon investigating i found that ErrorEvent is an API (Javascript) which is not supported in IE9.

ErrorEvent API: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ErrorEvent](http://API%20Link)

I am looking for the answer here
[ErrorEvent is not working for IE9 in Angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60412603/errorevent-is-not-working-for-ie9-in-angular-8)