# ErrorEvent is not working for IE9 in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, polyfills

Angular app throwing error for

> Retrieval error: ReferenceError: 'ErrorEvent' is undefined

it seems ErrorEvent is not compatible in IE 9 but works in higher versions.

I am looking for a polyfill or any alternation for ErrorEvent.

Comment: Have you tried googling "errorevent polyfill"?

Comment: @ChrisWalsh yes I tried  but there are no information I could find for errorevent polyfill sadly :(

Comment: have you looked at this one?  It suggests it polyfills IE9. https://github.com/theftprevention/event-constructor-polyfill.  I'm intrigued as to what client base you are supporting that still required support for IE9! @-)

Comment: @ChrisWalsh thank you for reference, I have tried this "event-constructor-polyfill" it doesn't fix my issue.
The requirement is from my customer and they are particular into IE as they are into finance.